# Processing an image on STM32 - C

Tags: c, camera, computer-vision, stm32, vision

I am doing some blob analysis on an embedded STM32H7 platform using C.

What do you think would be best way to accomplish this? Would it be possible to port openCV to STM32 and use those functions maybe? Let say I just want to use adaptive thresholding, would it be better to just write my own code for that or use some library that is already there?

Just to point out that I am obligated to use C. I know about some Python libraries for STM32 but I must use C for this project.

Thank you!

Comment: Adaptive thresholding is pretty trivial. If you know how it’s done, I bet it would be faster to implement it than porting a big library like OpenCV. Also OpenCV is C++, not C.

Comment: If you want to make your own adaptive threshold look up "Otsu's method" It's a fairly standard algorithm. As background it assumes bimodal data and reduces intra-class variance.
Your exact answer is highly dependent on your exact setup. How are you reading the data, is it RGB,HSY? Are you finding blobs by color? grayscale? All this information will change the solution. If you can update your question with details and maybe code of your image buffer this will help others understand your problem

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is not a free design service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your own functions is trivial. I have done minor on the subject and we had about 8 weeks to do it.

Porting OpenCV is not a good idea. It uses dynamic memory allocation everywhere which makes conservative use impossible and is written in C++.

Adaptive tresholding would take max a week of effort.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Implementing Adaptive thresholding is not that difficult. (Take into account that I have done it using mbed which makes it easier, and let me focus on implementing the algorithm). Also as Tarick says don't use dynamic memory

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn`t try to implement everything from zero

Try the opensource implementation first. If you can think about sth, that means some 1 else already did it. Someone else has done it.

See this link for details.

http://shervinemami.info/embeddedVision.html